# Cannot get my Custom Android View to display

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a custom control which does nothing except decorate the text which is displayed.  When I reference this class inside the main.xml like all the examples which I am reading and deploy this to the emulator, the widget just says "Problem Loading Widget."

I am beginning Android development and just trying to understand how to dev custom controls:

This is the ExtendedTextView control:

```
package uk.co.andrewrea.android;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExtendedTextView extends TextView {

    public ExtendedTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ExtendedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
    }

    public ExtendedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getText() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "***" + super.getText() + "***";
    }

}
```

And this is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_normal"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<uk.co.andrewrea.android.ExtendedTextView android:id="@+id/widget_textview"
  android:text="@string/hello"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
  android:padding="10dip"
  android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Cheers,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I reference this class inside the
>   main.xml like all the examples which I
>   am reading and deploy this to the
>   emulator, the widget just says
>   "Problem Loading Widget."

This message only appears for home screen app widgets. If that is what you are trying to build, you cannot use custom `View` classes with app widgets. You can only use custom `View` classes with `Activities`.

Comment: I think it's really unfortunate that they confused Views with Widgets by putting the standard Views in `android.widget`. Ugh, it really makes discussing problems like this a real pain sometimes.